# How to change x-axis labels when using facet-grid?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I would like to rename the x-axis labels on this plot using the labels mentioned in "mylabels", but it does not work (it only uses the first label for all the ticks). I guess the problem comes from the 'facet_grid" function as I can rename labels properly when I do not use this function. Any idea how to solve this issue?

```
mylabels <- c("MRA2x3","MRA2x4","MRB2x3","MRB2x4","whole milk")

ggplot(file, aes(x=as.factor(diet),y=ADG, fill= as.factor(farm))) + 
  geom_boxplot(width=1,alpha=0.5) +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE, alpha=0.6,guide = guide_legend(title = "Farm")) + 
  labs(y="Average daily gain", x = "Diet") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, max(file$ADG), by=0.2)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = mylabels) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 18),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        strip.text.x = element_blank()) + 
  facet_grid(~ diet, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

Comment: I think you can just change the variable `diet` to a factor with named levels. E.g., `file$diet = factor(file$diet, levels=mylabels)`

Comment: It'd help to have representative sample data, can you add the output of `dput(head(file,30))` (if there are a lot of columns, please reduce to just what is used here). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a vector of new names to the `facet_grid()` statement instead of the `scale_x_discrete` (delete that):

```
facet_grid(~ diet, 
           scales = "free_x",
           labeller = labeller(diet = mylabels))
```

The vector in `labeller` has to be a named vector: `c("old name1" = "new_name1", "old_name2" = "new_name2", ...)` so it maps the old names to the new names.